# ¿C# y Java son lenguajes multiparadigma?

Tags: java, c#, poo

No entiendo porque se consideran lenguajes multiparadigma, cuando según la documentación: "en C# la **función Main()** se debe definir como **un miembro estático de una clase**. Esto se debe a que **C# exige** que **todas las funciones y variables sean miembros de una clase o estructura**"

Y en Java sucede lo mismo. Por lo que el lenguaje y el compilador te están obligando a hacer uso del paradigma OOP.

Yo como programador de C y C++ imagino que en C# y Java no se puede hacer uso del Paradigma de programación Imperativo característico de C. Supongo que tampoco se puede usar en esos lenguajes el paradigma de programación Funcional y tampoco el de paradigma de programación Lógica. Ya que por ejemplo en la programación Funcional se usan funciones puras sin la intervención de nada más, por lo que se excluyen las clases.

Comment: ¿Dónde has leído que son lenguajes multiparadigma? Java es para POO exclusivamente. Podrías hacer todos los métodos de una clase static y usarlos como funciones, pero eso se consideraría un mal uso del lenguaje

Comment: Tal como comenta @PabloLozano, al menos en la lista de [lenguajes multiparadigma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categor%C3%ADa:Lenguajes_de_programaci%C3%B3n_multiparadigma) de Wikipedia, no hay rastros ni de Java, ni de C#. No me fiaría mucho del sitio, lugar o publicación de donde sacaste eso de que Java y/o C# se consideren lenguajes multiparadigma. Ahora, si la duda es a [*motu proprio*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motu_proprio), entonces ya puedes ir leyendo en la respuesta dada y en el comentario de Pablo. Saludos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Java SI es un lenguaje multiparadigma. Por ejemplo: estructurado, orientado a objetos y funcional. La mayoría de los lenguajes más usados actualmente son multiparadigma.

Answer (score 1):

Es cierto que Java y C# son lenguajes orientados a objetos, en los que todas las entidades son instancias de clases. Pero hay que tener en cuenta las nuevas versiones de ambos lenguajes, que introducen características externas a la orientación a objetos, al menos a nivel de lenguaje y de sintaxis. Otra cosa es el cómo se adaptan esas características a la orientación a objetos y a cada lenguaje concreto.

A diferencia de C++, C# y Java no permiten la programación imperativa estructurada clásica (funciones y procedimientos sin relación ninguna, ni concepto de clase, reflexión o meta programación, solo instrucciones y modularidad ofrecida a través de sub rutinas). Todo el código C# o Java debe estar dentro de métodos de una clase, ya sean de instancia o estáticos, y como mencionas, el `main` en ambos lenguajes debe ser declarado como método estático de una clase que funciona como lanzador de la aplicación.

Ahora bien, en Java, a pesar de que todo sean clases, desde Java 8 tenemos las interfaces funcionales y las expresiones lambda, que antes se manejaban como métodos de objetos que implementaban ciertas interfaces, como `Runnable`, u otras definidas por el usuario.

Un ejemplo claro es al aplicar un patrón estrategia clásico en Java (y que bien podría implementarse de igual forma en C#).

```
public interface EstrategiaCalculoInteres {
    public double calcularInteres(double dinerico);
}

public class EstrategiaCalculoNormal implements EstrategiaCalculoInteres { ... }
public class EstrategiaCalculoAgresiva implements EstrategiaCalculoInteres { ... }

public class CuentaBancaria {

    private double saldo;

    public void restarInteres(EstrategiaCalculoInteres estrategia) {
        saldo -= estrategia.calcularInteres(saldo);
    }
}

public class Ejemplo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CuentaBancaria cuenta = new CuentaBancaria(...);

        // Trabajamos con la cuenta

        EstrategiaCalculoInteres estrategia = new EstrategiaCalculoNormal();
        cuenta.restarInteres(estrategia);
    }
}
```

La forma más habitual de aplicar el patrón era utilizar una interfaz que proporciona un contrato para calcular algo o para llevar a cabo alguna acción.

En el ejemplo, existen varias clases que implementan una interfaz para calcular un interés y que realizan el cálculo de manera diferente. Entonces, una clase (`CuentaBancaria` en este caso) puede hacer uso de la interfaz para aplicar dicho cálculo, y en la llamada correspondiente desde el `main`, o desde un controlador, se le proporciona una estrategia de cálculo, que no es otra cosa que un objeto de alguna de las clases que implementa la interfaz de cálculo.

Ahora, con Java 8 y la introducción de las interfaces funcionales y las expresiones lambda, quedaría reducido a lo siguiente, que ya no es orientación a objetos pura.

```
public class CuentaBancaria {

    /* Atributos varios */

    public void restarInteres(Function<double, double> estrategiaCalculo) {
        saldo -= estrategiaCalculo.apply(this);    // Similar al caso anterior
    }
}

public class EjemploConLambda {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CuentaBancaria cuenta = new CuentaBancaria(...);

        // Trabajamos con la cuenta

        cuenta.restarInteres(d => 7.8 * d);    // Expresión lambda en vez de objeto
    }
}
```

En este momento, la orientación a objetos, a pesar de ser la mayor parte del lenguaje, se rompe con la introducción de elementos externos a la propia orientación a objetos, al menos a nivel de sintaxis de lenguaje. Internamente sigue siendo una clase anónima que implementa una interfaz, en este caso funcional.

Pero es más, en C# existe un concepto similar, que es el de los delegados, que se utiliza junto con las expresiones lambda para conseguir el mismo efecto: definir un contrato e implementarlo al vuelo mediante expresiones lambda. En este caso, los delegados se parecen más a definir un tipo signatura, y las expresiones lambda a métodos anónimos.

Pero la cosa no se queda ahí, en C# además puedes desactivar el contexto seguro y empezar a trabajar con punteros tipo C y datos en crudo.

Y no solo eso, porque mientras que en Java los métodos *getter* y *setter* son métodos normales que consultan o establecen valores, en C# tienes la evolución de los mismos con la introducción de las *propiedades*, que son la conjunción de los métodos *get* y *set*, pero que se manejan como si fueran un solo campo, ya que no hace falta poner los clásicos paréntesis de un método, y el *setter* se invoca mediante el operador de asignación.

Aunque solo sea en un contexto limitado, ya se pierde la distinción clásica entre los campos de una clase y los métodos que los manejan, ya que estás utilizando un método con sintaxis de campo.

```
public class Libro {
    public string Titulo { get; set; }  // Propiedad de lectura-escritura
    public Libro(string titulo) => Titulo = titulo;  // Cuerpo de expresión
}

public class Ejemplo {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Libro libro = new Libro("El cuerpo del día");
        libro.Titulo = "Prueba de sabor";    // Se invoca al setter
    }
}
```

Internamente, una propiedad de C# no es otra cosa que un método *set* y uno *get*, con un espacio de almacenamiento que puedes definir explícitamente, o en algunos casos, el compilador lo agrega de manera automática. Estas son las llamadas propiedades auto implementadas.

Comment: No se mucho de C# por lo que mi comentario se acota a Java. Lo introducido en java 8 de funciones lambda no rompre con la OOP, es solo lo que llaman "sugar syntax", es decir escribir de un forma más acotada lo que llevaría un poco más de lineas si se usara la syntaxis "común". Y la duda que tengo es porque decís que la OOP necesita un lenguaje fuertemente tipado?

Comment: solo me quedo en la ultima parte.. Titulo no es un metodo.. nunca.. es un getter y un setter, es sugar syntax... y se usa sobre todo en mvvm... y luego, ahora, siguiendo con el azucar, el constructor no necesita recibir el titulo, porque si Titulo es una propiedad se pasa directamente al objeto sin constructor... ojo con confundir el azucar con lo que hace el lenguaje por atras...

Comment: *C# y Java no permiten la programación imperativa clásica...* Eso no es verdad, ambos lenguajes tienen soporte para el [paradigma imperativo](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/i/imp-programming.htm).

Comment: @Juan es cierto que en Java las expresiones lambda son solo una forma de definir clases anónimas que implementan interfaces. Pero a nivel de lenguaje, de sintaxis, siguen siendo expresiones lambda. Sin embargo, como comentas, un lenguaje orientado a objetos no necesita ser fuertemente tipado. Algunos de ellos, los que tradicionalmente eran más populares, lo eran, pero es cierto que cada vez se apuesta por lenguajes con tipados débiles, y algunos de ellos son orientados a objetos. Editaré la respuesta para una mayor corrección.

Comment: @gbianchi los _getter_ y los _setter_ son métodos. Las propiedades son la conjunción de ambos métodos, más un espacio de almacenamiento que puede ser implícito o explícito. En el contexto de la asignación en el código, se está invocando al _setter_, que es a lo que me refería. Por otro lado, es un ejemplo, y el constructor puede tener o no un parámetro. Con dicho constructor solo quise hacer patente que en el ejemplo voy a cambiar un valor que estaba previamente almacenado en la zona de memoria que hace de _backing_ de la propiedad.

Comment: @MrDave1999 depende de la fuente que leas, algunos consideran la orientación a objetos como parte del paradigma imperativo, y otros lo consideran un paradigma en sí mismo. Hay argumentos de peso en ambas direcciones. Yo personalmente lo considero un paradigma propio, ya que no le ordenas al computador directamente que haga cosas, sino que le pides a los objetos que hagan cosas por ti. Por otro lado, si te saltas la orientación a objetos poniendo todo tu código en métodos estáticos, eso no es programación estructurada clásica, es un mal uso de la orientación a objetos.

Comment: @EequiisVásquez No puede ser un mal uso de la orientación a objetos, porque los métodos estáticos no forman parte de la POO, sino, es una característica propia del lenguaje. Tanto Java como C# tienen soporte para el paradigma estructurado, porque puedes recurrir al uso de funciones (en Java o c# se los conoce como métodos estáticos) + estructuras de control. Y **ojo**, la forma como implemente C o C++ la programación estructurada no tiene nada que ver con la forma como lo haga Java o C#..

Comment: @MrDave1999 yo sí considero que utilizar métodos estáticos para saltarte el uso de las clases es un mal uso de la orientación a objetos. Para empezar porque los métodos estáticos tienen que estar dentro de una clase. Pero no solo eso, ten en cuenta que las clases son objetos, y que los métodos estáticos son métodos que se pueden ejecutar como métodos de instancia utilizando a la clase como objeto. Pero además, los métodos y atributos estáticos no fueron añadidos para saltarse la POO, sino para definir características/atributos propios de clases, y no de sus instancias.